# Transformations not correcting significant skews

Tags: data-transformation

I am running an experiment which measured using Likert Scales and I have 6 variables out of 24 which either have significant skewness or kurtosis. These are mixed with some positive and some negative values.

I transformed my data using log transformations, Square root transformations, reciprocal transformations and reverse score transformations, but this did not solve the problem. 
In fact, all this did was give me a greater number of significantly skewed variables (for example square root transformations left me with 11 variables significantly skewed or suffering from kurtosis).

Is there any other type of data transformations that anyone can recommend that may help, especially when some skews are positive and others are negative? If so, does anyone know the SPSS syntax involved?

Comment: (i) Likert scale variable are discrete  --  transformation usually won't do much on individual scale items; ...  (ii) Why are you transforming these variables?

Comment: Hello Glen_b. I'm transforming the variables because I read that skewed data could be corrected using various transformations, and a paper with an experiment similar to my own used square root transformations to address problems with their distributions. I'm new to this so was following this example. This paper also used likert-scale measurements

Comment: Back up one step. *Why* do you think these variables need to be "corrected"?

Comment: I assumed that because 4 variables are significantly skewed and 2 variables suffer from significant kurtosis that they would not conform to the assumptions of normality and could not be used with parametric analyses. I intend to conduct ANOVAs and a multiple regression, and I worry that the model may overfit my data if not normally distributed. Also, this work is for my thesis and I'm worried that if I note that these predictors were significantly skewed/kurt but then do not make any adjustments they may butcher me. :)

Comment: I hasten to add that none of my four DVs were skewed or suffered from kurtosis.

Comment: What do you think is assumed to be normal? (A hint: Neither the IVs *nor even the marginal distribution of the DVs* are assumed to be normal in ANOVA or multiple regression. If someone attacks you for not satisfying an assumption that's not required, you should be able to learn enough to explain to them why they're gravely mistaken. If you're using the classical hypothesis tests/confidence intervals, then *something* is assumed to be normal, but none of those things are. Even if the actual assumptions weren't satisfied, transformation may break other assumptions!)

Comment: I see. So transforming the data is not a magic wand in stats. Often better to leave the data as it is and merely report that some skewness was observed, but not deemed to be a problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Pretty much. Skewness in IVs is irrelevant to the inference. Skewness in DVs can be due to patterns in the IVs (what's assumed normal is the error term). There are times when transformation has value in regression, but not nearly as often as transformation is used to solve nonexistent problems. It's more important to think about whether the linearity, variance and independence assumptions hold. (Even if the normality of error terms didn't hold there are ways to deal with that without transforming.)

Comment: Thank you Glen. That's really helpful advice. My data meet all the assumptions of MR so shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't sound like you have any problems. On "*My data meet all the assumptions of MR so shouldn't be too much of a problem.*" -- actually, I doubt that your data meet all - and indeed, quite possibly any - of the assumptions. Rather, I imagine they don't so badly violate the assumptions that it's reasonable to proceed as if they assumptions were met; the essential question ('how badly is my inference affected by assumption violations?') is probably answered by 'hardly impacted at all'. In reality, few regression assumptions are ever quite true.

Comment: (Not that you'd necessarily want to raise that if there's people who'll criticize a failure to meet non-existent assumptions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few points

1. If your variables are individual Likert items on (say) a 7 point scale, then it is arguable whether they should be treated as continuous at all.
2. This *sounds* like you are using these variables as independent variables. If so, why do you want them to be normally distributed?
3. It also sounds like you applied all the transformations willy-nilly to all the variables. This is not right. Positive skew can be corrected (at least sometimes) by logs. Negative skew would be made worse; negative skew could be dealt with (perhaps) by squaring or reciprocal. But, again, applying these transformations to a Likert scale makes relatively little sense, usually.

Comment: Hello Peter. Thank you for your reply. 2. The variables will be used as predictors in a multiple regression.  I am actually following a similar method to a paper conducting an experiment not too dissimilar from my own. In this paper the authors used square root transformations to address problems with their distributions. Usually, do people only transform the DV? I have read also that when you do a transformation it should be to all of the variables in your data, not just one, is this correct? 3. You're right, I did transform a bit willy-nilly. I tried all of the transformation methods...

Comment: ... to see if any would reduce skewness and kurtosis.

Comment: additionally, my DV is not significantly skewed

Comment: If you transform variables, it should be to address assumptions of the model; OLS assumes that the residuals are normally distributed, not the variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited with thanks to @Peter Flom for correction in comment on original answer**

If you want to examine the effects of covariates on Likert scale responses from multiple respondents, use ordinal probit or ordinal logit regression to estimate the effects of covariates on the ordered log odds of a response being in a particular category (in the case of ordered logit) or marginal effects on an observation's position within the latent scale (in the case of ordered probit).

Definitely needed that second cup of coffee if I was originally thinking that Likert scale analysis calls for multinomial regression!

Comment: On a single Likert item as DV, often ordinal logistic will be better than nominal. Likert variables are at least ordinal.  However, it appears that the poster is using Likert scales as independent variables.

Comment: Ah, good point! I shall edit my response accordingly!

Comment: Sure, revise away!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am reading up on it now!